# rspec test, how to get the id in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have a rsepc test for my controller, in my test, I have the following code snippet:

```
...
params= {SOME PARAMETERS}
post :create, params
```

the above code test the **create** method in my controller, the **create** method create a instance object and save it into database.

Now the problem is how can I get the **id** of the created instance object in database?

It seems (I am not sure) I need to query the test database for this object, how to query?
(PS: I know there is **Factory** can be used to create object instance, BUT this is a test for controller, use Factory will loose the purpose of testing controller's create method. So, please do not advice me to use **Factory**)

I would like to know how to get the id of my created object instance based on my code? Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign the object in your controller with something like

```
@object = Object.new(params[:object]
```

then it'll be available using the assigns method, so you could do the following:

```
assigns[:object].id
```

and it will return the id, assuming it saved successfully.

-- edit --

with RSpec 2 it seems assigns is a method call, so you provide the attribute like so

```
assigns(:object)
```

instead of the old hash-like behaviour

Comment: I've updated my answer as I noticed you're using RSpec 2. You will get a deprecation warning with the old syntax.