# RSpec: How to get definitive list of example IDs

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I want to run specific `rspec` examples and have been specifying line numbers in the command line to do this. But every time I change something, the line number shift and this is a pain.

`rspec` has the ability to run a specific example, or range of examples by "id" using this syntax in the command line:

```
rspec path/to/a_spec.rb[1:5,1:6] # run the 5th and 6th examples/groups defined in the 1st group
```

Is there a way to get rspec to list all the example ids so I do not need to manually comb through the code counting `describe`, `context`, `it`, `scenarios`, etc. calls manually?

Comment: why are you not using --tag ? just out of curiosity.  in this case, it might just make better sense if it's shifting too many times.

Comment: A good point. `tag` is an option for me, but it requires changing the test to add the tag.  I am open to that, but when I learned about the test ID specification I wanted to see if there was a straightforward way to get that ID.  My documentation reading and Googling did not turn much up, so I wanted to see if the Hive Mind could help. If there is no way to get a list of IDs, then tagging would probably be easier than counting.

Comment: see if this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375756/rspec-test-how-to-get-the-id-in-my-case

Comment: @OnurG, Thanks, but the ID I am looking for is not a `ruby` object id, but an `rspec` example id.  If you run `rspec --help` and look for `path/to/a_spec.rb[1:5]` you will see where I learned about this from.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the code a bit and discussing with the maintainers, I learned that there is no native option to display test IDs, but they are available and one can write custom reporters to display them.